# extract version from package.json with bash inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "version": "echo $npm_package_version"
  },
```

One of the stage in Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Build'){
    sh 'npm install'
    def packageVersion = sh 'npm run version'
    echo $packageVersion
    sh 'VERSION=${packageVersion} npm run build'
}
```

I got version from npm script output, but following line

```
echo $packageVersion
```

return null

Is packageVersion value not correctly assigned?

Edited:
when using Pipeline Utility Steps with following code

```
stage('Build'){
    def packageJSON = readJSON file: 'package.json'
    def packageJSONVersion = packageJSON.version
    echo packageJSONVersion
    sh 'VERSION=${packageJSONVersion}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BRANCH_NAME} npm run build'
        }
```

I get

```
[Pipeline] echo
1.1.0
[Pipeline] sh
[...] Running shell script + VERSION=_16_SOME_BRANCH npm run build
```

So I am able to extract version, but still cannot pass it when running script

Comment: I have no experience with node.js, but in case the `package.json` contains the version, you could also read it via [`readJSON`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).

Comment: Thanks for hint, I have edited my post with using readJSON

Comment: I added the `--silent` option to `npm run script` to avoid added output to be captured

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your edit using `readJSON`, you now get string interpolation wrong. Variables within single quotes are *not* replaced in Groovy, only within double quotes.

```java
sh 'VERSION=${packageJSONVersion}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BRANCH_NAME} npm run build'
```

must be

```java
sh "VERSION=${packageJSONVersion}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BRANCH_NAME} npm run build"
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`sh`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) step by default returns nothing, so `packageVersion` should be `null`.

To return the output of the executed command, use it like this:

```
sh(script: 'npm run version', returnStdout: true)
```

This variant of sh returns the output instead of printing it.

Actually, I am wondering, why `echo $packageVersion` doesn't fail with an error, as this variable is not defined, but should be `echo packageVersion`.

Comment: following gives me empty string: def packageVersion = sh(script: 'npm run version', returnStdout: true)
echo "version:${packageVersion}"

Comment: Beware of the stray quote in the code snippet

Answer (score 3):

If you have Node available:

```bash
stage {
  steps {
    script {
      def version = sh(script: "node -p \"require('./package.json').version\"", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you're using Docker:

```bash
def version = sh(script: "docker run --rm node:slim node -p \"require('./package.json').version\"", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Then you can:

```bash
sh "VERSION=${version}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BRANCH_NAME} npm run build"
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach. Works like a glance.

I just want to add one more note. I had to add it to env, something like "env. version = version" to make it available for further stages.

Answer (score 2):

For my it this:

```
sh(script: "grep \"version\" package.json | cut -d '\"' -f4 | tr -d '[[:space:]]'", returnStdout: true)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code. Submitting code only as the answer is discouraged on Stack Overflow and potential to be deleted.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**Full version number:**

```
PACKAGE_VERSION = sh returnStdout: true, script: '''grep 'version' package.json | cut -d '"' -f4 | tr '\n' '\0''''
echo "Current package version: $PACKAGE_VERSION"
$ > 1.2.3
```

**Major version only:**

```
PACKAGE_VERSION = sh returnStdout: true, script: '''grep 'version' package.json | cut -d '"' -f4 | cut -d '.' -f1 | tr '\n' '\0''''
echo "Current package Major version: $PACKAGE_VERSION"
$ > 1
```

Comment: This worked for me:
version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "grep 'version' package.json | cut -d '\"' -f4 | tr '\\n' '\\0'")

Comment: @RakeshYembaram comment should be an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
stage('Read JSON') {
    steps {
        script {
            def packageJson = readJSON file: 'package.json'
            def packageVersion = packageJSON.version
            echo "${packageJSONVersion}"
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet worked for me: Credits to @Ferenc Takacs

version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "grep 'version' package.json | cut -d '"' -f4 | tr '\n' '\0'")

Answer (score 0):

This command will take exact property `version: ...` in `package.json` and can work on both Mac and Linux. The other solutions using `grep` will not give you correct answer in case of you have > 1 `version` keyword in your `package.json` (it'll return all of them instead of just the one you want)

```
awk -F'"' '/"version": ".+"/{ print $4; exit; }' package.json
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your code. Submitting code only as answer is discouraged on Stack Overflow and potential to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To access an npm environment variable outside the scope of a run-script, parse the variable with bash:

```
$ npm run env | grep npm_package_version | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Author: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/08/14/package-json-version/